# Unable to launch activity from FCM onMessageReceived when app is killed

Tags: android, android-activity, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-8.0-oreo, launch

I want to open an activity when a push notification is received from FCM to my Android Oreo. But it's not working. I have tried adding an HTTP call in `onMessageReceived` method and that works as expected. But it will not start an activity, as in the code below:

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(@NonNull RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);

    //http call which succeeds

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

The manifest has this service definition:

```
    <service
        android:name=".services.CheckerService"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

Looking forward to some expert suggestions.

Comment: @Jason, the `onMessageReceived` is indeed called even after app is swiped off left from recent apps, as I can see from the HTTP call it does.

Comment: @Jason, What I have done inside `onMessageReceived` is start a websocket connection. So when I swipe off from recents, I can see that this websocket is closed, and when a new notification is arrived, it re-establishes the websocket. So I know it was killed. Is there any other way to check if the app is still running after it got swiped off?

Answer (score 1):

Check if the `android:showOnLockScreen`, `android:showWhenLocked`, and `android:turnScreenOn` parameters are set to `"true"` in your `AndroidManifest.xml`?